# LINQ To XML reading child element values filtered on attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new to LINQ to XML and I have the following example partially working but am stuck on how to read one of the element values, CustomFieldResponse/Values/Value when the FieldCode attribute for CustomFieldResponse equals "Bio"

The other two values ID and WebsiteID read fine no problem and I am able to insert them into my SQL table. But I have no idea how to reference the value for Bio.

```
<members>
   <member>
      <ID>BF175DE0</ID>
      <WebsiteID>19186</WebsiteID>
      <CustomFieldResponses>
         <CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="Bio" Visibility="">
            <Values>
               <Value>This is the value i am trying to put in bio</Value>
            </Values>
         </CustomFieldResponse>
         <CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="facebook" Visibility="">
            <Values>
               <Value>http://facebook.com/myidhere</Value>
            </Values>
         </CustomFieldResponse>
      </CustomFieldResponses>
   </member>
</members>



string ID, WebsiteID;


XElement xelement = XElement.Load("members.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> members = xelement.Elements();

foreach (var member in members)
{
ID = member.Element("ID").Value;
WebsiteID = member.Element("WebsiteID").Value;

var bio = from a in member.Elements("CustomFieldResponses")
    from b in a.Elements("CustomFieldResponse")
    where b.Attribute("FieldCode").Value == "Bio"
    from c in b.Elements("Values")
    select new { bio = c.Element("Value").Value };


    SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT Members (ID, WebsiteID, Bio) VALUES                 ('" + ID + "','" + WebsiteID + "','" + bio + "')", dataConnection);
    dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using XPath ?

```
var xpathQuery = "//CustomFieldResponse[@FieldCode='Bio']/Values/Value";
var val = xelement.XPathSelectElement(xpathQuery);
```

or with pure Linq2Xml

```
var value = (string)xelement.Descendants("CustomFieldResponse")
                    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("FieldCode") == "Bio")
                    .Descendants("Value")
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var bio = (from fieldResponseCollection in member.Elements("CustomFieldResponses")
    from fieldResponse in fieldResponseCollection.Elements("CustomFieldResponse")
    from responseValue in fieldResponse.Elements("Values")
    select responseValue.Element("Value")
    where fieldResponse.Attribute("FieldCode").Value == "Bio")
.First();
```